# Support of expand command in breeze with the Mongo Library

Tags: breeze

Can someone tell me when the expand command in breeze will be available in combination with MongoDB?

Kind regards
Dominik

Answer (score 1):

The EntityQuery 'expand' function is not likely to be implemented for MongoDB because 'expand' conceptually requires a 'join' which is a feature that Mongo does not implement.

However, the idea within MongoDB is that an object's children ( or relations if you are coming from a relational background) are actually stored and returned with the parents.  From a **breeze** perspective this means that we treat all of these related children objects as complex objects that are automatically returned when you query the parent. In other words, all of the "expands" that you are likely to want are automatically part of the results of your queries.

The only problem occurs when you actually try to use MongoDB in a relational manner, i.e. where you store the ID of an object in one collection as a property of an object in another collection. From a MongoDB ( and **breeze**) perspective this would mean you would need to perform another query to get this related data.

We did think about translating breeze 'expand's into a series of nested queries but it really does go against the "MongoDB" mindset and the performance of such queries can be terrible.  ... and we weren't sure that it would be that useful or desirable to the majority of MongoDB developers.

In general, if this occurs a lot in your data, then MongoDB is probably not the right database to use, because you will end up manually "joining" your data, which is a very tedious process in Mongo.  This is one of the cases where a relational database really is a better choice.